# Import component twice

Tags: react-native

Can't find a good example of how to do this, but I have a component that I would like to use twice in a component.

Right now I just import by:

```
import Picker from 'react-native-picker';
```

Which for this particular component only imports 1 instance of the Picker object. Is there a way to important two independent objects.. such as

```
import Picker as picker1, picker2 from 'react-native-picker';
```

Is there something out there like this?

----EDIT:
Here is the example code of how to use this particular component. I was trying to keep it specific as I know the community here likes it better when it is more general to benefit more people...thanks!

```
import Picker from 'react-native-picker';

    let data = [];
    for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
        data.push(i);
    }

    Picker.init({
        pickerData: data,
        selectedValue: [59],
        onPickerConfirm: data => {
            console.log(data);
        },
        onPickerCancel: data => {
            console.log(data);
        },
        onPickerSelect: data => {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    Picker.show();
```

Comment: What's the use-case for this?

Comment: @TomWalters Its just a picker component someone in the React Native community built. I figured you could just use it like <Button> </Button> and make as many as you want, but seems to be more imported like a variable.. like you use Picker.open() to activate the picker

Comment: I added the example code to the bottom of my post

Comment: If you import it twice, you'll only get two references to the same thing, so it will not solve your problem. I'm not sure how you'd go about creating multiple pickers with [react-native-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-picker). It would be easy if it was written like a proper React component, but from the API it seems to break completely with the react way of doing things. Have you tried React Native's [Picker](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker.html)?

Comment: ahh, okay.. i can probably just make a copy of this one.. thanks!

Comment: Hey, why don't you create a wrapper component which wraps your `react-native-picker` an lets name it MyPicker? And once you import `MyPicker` in any component you can use as many `<MyPicker />` as you want in your `render` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably have to create two different components in different files and then import Picker1 and Picker2 to the parent component.

You can either do everything you need inside these components or give them a `ref` prop in the parent and you'll have access to their methods.

```
import Picker1 from './picker1'
import Picker2 from './picker2'

class ParentComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Picker1 ref={(picker1) => this.picker1 = picker1} />
        <Picker2 ref={(picker2) => this.picker2 = picker2} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah, that is going to be my approach.. thanks so much!